# iOS app in non-english language

Tags: ios, xcode, localization, app-store-connect

I have developed an app which should be in Norwegian language only.  The app does not use localisation, since it should appear in one language only (Norwegian). However, I have set "*Localisation native development region*" to "no" in the Info.plist file.  I also use base localisation.

The app launches and behaves correctly in Norwegian language for any device language and regional setting.  So far, so good.

The problem arises on the app-store, where the app language states English and not Norwegian as I would expect. I have created the iTunes Connect record for Norwegian only, and I believe the problem is related to information iTunes Connect extracts from the app-image it self. However, I cannot figure out which setting in Xcode that needs to be altered in order to reflect Norwegian on the app-store.  I use Xcode 7.2.

Any clue on how to solve this issue would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Have you set the language to norwegian in iTunes Connect too?

Comment: Yes, language is set to norwegian in iTunes Connect.

Comment: What's the app called, then i can check it on the AppStore. If the only language shown in itunes connect is norwegian something doesnt seem right

Comment: Thanks Jacob, that would be great.  The app is called "Hagen Din XT".

Comment: This is what it shows in the AppStore window:

Languages: English, Norwegian Bokmål
https://itunes.apple.com/no/app/hagen-din/id593299918?mt=8

Comment: The app is named "Hagen Din XT".  The App you are referring to i believe does display correct language setting.

Comment: Thanks Jacob, I had done exactly as you said.  Still, app language is displayed as English (English, Norwegian on my other app).

Comment: Yeah it's because you need to upload a new build (get it processed to the App Store), until then it won't change. Please accept the answer below :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally managed to get this working by:

1. Use the latest version (7.3.1) of Xcode
2. Add InfoPlist.strings and Localizable.strings to the project
3. Add Base and Norwegian Localisation to the project
4. Localize InfoPlist.strings and Localizable.strings to Norwegian
5. Localise Storyboard/XIB files to Base and Norwegian
6. Make sure all other localisations are removed from the project and delete the belonging files and folders.  Only Base and Norwegian should be left
7. Set "Localisation native development region" to "nb-NO" in info.plist
8. Add "CFBundleDisplayName" = "Your App" to InfoPlist.strings

This should also apply to any other language for single language apps.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is the following:

1. Go to iTunes Connect
2. Select your app
3. Choose a new build
4. Tap on the language (Where the arrow points)
5. Select a new language
6. When you have added the new language you are able to delete the english.

[image]

Comment: I checked my iTunes Connect settings for the version already published, and I had already done exactly what you suggest.  Only Norwegian localisation language checked for the already published version.   So, despite everything appears to be correctly set before I submitted the binary, App Store displays "Language: English".   I will submit a new binary, just to make sure I haven't missed out any steps.  I believe the problem could also be related to localisation settings extracts from the app-image. If so, there must be localisation settings in Xcode reflected on the app-store (?).

Comment: It cannot be related to Xcode. It's only in iTunesConnect.

Comment: This link describes this further:  https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/DisplayInMoreLanguages.html   As you say,  the language information provided in iTunes Connect isn’t the same as the language information built into the app itself. However, the list of languages displayed in the store under Languages is set in the app build, and this is the information I'm referring to.  It should be possible to control this by setting "Localisation native development region" in Info.plist

Comment: That's not it. This only means what kind of native language you are programming in. Lets say there are three types of users: 1. American, 2. Norwegian and 1 Dane. Let's say that you localize your apps strings (NSlocalization) to both norwegian and english. This will now result in the norwegian users will have it in norwegian, and the american will have it in the english. The dane will also have it in norwegian as there is no localized string for danish, and therefor it takes the app's native localization development region, which is norwegian. This has nothing todo with iTunes Connect.

Comment: This is also my understanding of the "Localisation native development region".  In addition, for non-localised apps (as in my case where it should be Norwegian only), iTunes Connect should use this information to display "Language: Norwegian" in AppStore.   But, AppStore displays this as "Language: English".  If I set the development region to english and localise my app to Norwegian, AppStore will display "Languages: English, Norwegian". So,  what I am i doing wrong here?

Comment: Also, if I set the development region to no (norwegian) and localise my app to Norwegian, AppStore still displays "Languages: English, Norwegian".

Comment: Per... Please read what i'm writing. It's the way you've setup the stuff in iTunes Connect. Make sure that there is only one language in the next version of your app, and it's marked as primary (in iTunes Connect). This will fix the "problem".

Comment: Jacob, I have correctly set the Localisable Information in iTunes Connect to Norwegian as primary language under both "App Information" and the version ready for sale.  No other languages are checked, - and thats for sure.   I have double checked that many times according to your explanation.

Comment: It was set correctly to Norwegian from the early start.  But, yes I have updated and english is still there.   I could always send you some screenshots, if you still think this is related to iTunes Connect language settings.

Comment: It's definitely related to the iTunes Connect.

Comment: I don't think this is related to localisation settings in iTunes Connect.  I will do further investigations and revert as soon as I have more information on this.